# Default value of textbox changed by user

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

Using c# winforms

I want to have a textbox that saves what the user last input in it. In this case, I want to have a textbox with the gst of the country in it which can be changed by the user and saved so that it stays changed the next time the application is open again. I can only think of creating a small table in sqlite and saving the data there then calling the last saved data but I'm not sure if it would work and I just want to know are there any other ways?

Comment: Instead of an sql table you may save it in a file. BUT, if you already have a DB(even if you don't actually), DB are great and created to store data, insert it, update it, etc.
If you don't have Db yet, you may want to look at NoSQL

Comment: "I want to have a textbox that saves what the user last input in it" how big is the data here? "I want to have a textbox with the gst of the country" is it the same textbox? so basically you want only to save 1 number?

Comment: Yea that's what I thought. I already have an sqlite db so either ways still got to use it. Is there a way to insert the data from the db directly to the textbox btw? At most I can think of is through datagridview.

Comment: Just 7.0 or 11. Small number. Same textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to save this one string, you can use the settings. To do this, create a string under Project --> Propetries --> Settings. (In my case I called it LastText)

Use it like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text =  Properties.Settings.Default.LastText
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.LastText = textBox1.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```